# Unable to understand the semantics of keyof in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, keyof

I have the following simple example of where `K extends keyof T` is declared, but the result of the return type inferred for `findMember` is different, I really don't understand why there is such a difference.

I also created a link to TypeScript Playground [HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwIwB4AqA+aA3gFDSnQBmAlgHYAmAsgKYC2ARo-JgNLSMAeAF0Z0YAa0YBPROWjZoAXmjipMvAApqYZowBc0LgEo92ANpcAuoRJkb8RgOTxqhAL7RIss+YDc10i6IAolBIGAQUVAAmHAAafV5BYVoxSWlZBSVU1XxiGyo6JjYODS1dfSNPCysbW3tHZwI3D1MLXxsAoJoheHIwYEZoAAUOCEQGvwpKeAgBADlSvRn4GgBzNrJwGfntRYFl6jWJsBWy6mQi+HXSMFpaOyhGCD0AQXh4MAlMXJrSJcZ7Xb7Q4-UjASgCCSA1ZXGoAL0oqChBxhLlwgSIwTGM2gKyQaHQGWojAA7nA8RhMMNpmNcGoDL4APQM6AASWo5A4dlo0AhqAGlBgr3enwI0D+ALFe2h0DBEKRa2g8MRkqB3mgqN8wCxAnct3uEEeBMUuIi6AAdPkGCx2PA1AByG53R4GiB2+kYrXUbEmtCRQkkskRaJU0bUWnupms9mcxjc3n8mBLVbQAA+0DOF1T0CFHy+Kv+AnlatlkJV0qVRfVuE12t1ToeED9xvJkQtNCtF3tjv1jzd3iAA)

```
class Group1<T> {
    findMember<K extends keyof T = keyof T>(name: K): T[K] {
        return {} as T[K];
    }
}

class Group2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    findMember(name: K): T[K] {
        return {} as T[K];
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    addresses: Array<{
        street: string;
        city: string;
        zip: string;
    }>
}

const group1 = new Group1<Person>();
// Inferred type is Array<{ street: string; city: string; zip: string; }>;
const addresses1 = group1.findMember('addresses');

const group2 = new Group2<Person>();
// Inferred type is string | number | Array<{ street: string; city: string; zip: string; }>;
const addresses2 = group2.findMember('addresses');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `group1.findMember('addresses')`, `K` can be inferred as `"addresses"`, so `Person["addresses"]` is returned.

In `group2.findMember('addresses')`, `K` is a type parameter from the top-level class declaration. 
Its default type `keyof T` (all keys of `T`) is used, as you did not specify `K`, when an instance was created with `const group2 = new Group2<Person>();`. So you end up with the return type `Person["firstName" | "lastName" | "age" | "addresses"]`, which is the union of all possible property values.

If you use `const group2 = new Group2<Person, "addresses">()`, results should be the same.

Comment: That makes sense, is there any way  to achieve the same thing for `Group1` using what I have for `Group2` without making `findMember` a generic method?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwIwB4AqAaaA0tAKYAeALsQHYAmMA1sQJ6IBm02AfNAN4BQ0QdGCIqEcvGTByieAApU8AJYA3MJWgBbJgWYAuQvkWr1xaIgBGAKwPYAlL2gBfPgKGsltALLFNF4vIO-EIh0PDE5MjwVNDkABZKEAB0llYA2vGJSdq6TAC6boIuLnwiYuRhxDAAvNBUxADucEho6HIARGDt+DxgBu2siIjtTnZJHt6+-oEA3EA) (not sure what you want here)? The only difference between the two is where generics are defined.

Comment: What I want is the ability to type check what I pass to `findMember` without making `findMember` generic, and I want to be able to pass every property that exists in `T`, and to have TypeScript infer `K` for me

Comment: I don't think that it is possible without. `keyof` will always return the union of all keys and `T[keyof T]` returns all possible property values. You have to set a generic constraint somewhere to limit the selection to a chosen property. This type parameter can be on the class or on the method, you could also include some instance state like in the example.